# How to get constructor by inexact type of parameters?

Tags: java, reflection

I need to find a constructor, which can accept both class and it's superclass.

The `get` method does not work, causing `NoSuchMethodException`:

```
package tests.java;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class Try_ConstructorReflection {

    public static class A {

    }

    public static class A1 extends A {

    }

    public static class A2 extends A {

    }

    public static class B {
        public B(A a) {
        }
    }

    public static class B1 {
        public B1(A1 a) {
        }
    }

    public static class B2 {
        public B2(A2 a) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {

        Class<?> cls = B.class;

        Constructor<?> cons = cls.getConstructor(B1.class);

        System.out.println(cons.toString());

    }

}
```

Is the only way to accomplish the task is to enumerate all constructor manually with [`getConstructors()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors--)?

Comment: your intention is somewhat unclear, how do B1 and B2 relate to the question? In it's current form `class B` doesn't have any constructor which could take `class B1` thus the failure.

Comment: If you don't have a constructor in class `B` that accepts a parameter of type `B1`, then you'll get `NoSuchMethodException`. (Btw, I think you have a typo there, maybe it should be `A1`?)